# Optimization issues with positive definite constraints

Tags: convex-optimization

I have an optimization problem where I have to optimize a function f(A) where A is a matrix(sparse).

Like

A =
\begin{array}{cccc}
A_1 & A_0 & A_0 & 0  \\
A_0 & A_2 & 0 & A_0   \\
A_0 & 0 & A_3 & A_0  \\
0 & A_0 & A_0 & A_4  \\
\end{array}

A is a positive definite matrix and the variables are $A_i$. I want to optimize over these variables with the constraint that the matrix A is positive definite. Are there any softwares to help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

The CVX software package for MATLAB can handle semidefinite prodramming problems (SDPs).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of packages for semidefinite programming (SDP). I have experience using [CVXOPT](http://cvxopt.org/) and [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org/) python packages.

Also take a look at [Peter Wittek](https://peterwittek.com/sdp-in-python.html)'s blog on well curated list of SDP solver packages for different versions of Python.